# sparse_hash_map is very slow for specific data

Tags: python, c++, performance, hashmap, cython

**tl;dr:** why does key lookup in `sparse_hash_map` become about 50x slower for specific data?

---

I am testing the speed of *key lookups* for `sparse_hash_map` from Google's sparsehash library using a very simple Cython wrapper I've written. The hashtable contains `uint32_t` keys and `uint16_t` values. For random keys, values and queries I am getting more than 1M lookups/sec. However, for the specific data I need the performance barely exceeds 20k lookups/sec.

The wrapper is [here](https://github.com/Pastafarianist/cython-sparsehash). The table which runs slowly is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Jnpz9ldbuHUzFuRGhUSkVtYWc/view?usp=sharing). The benchmarking code is:

`benchmark.pyx`:

```
from sparsehash cimport SparseHashMap
from libc.stdint cimport uint32_t
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
import time
import numpy as np

def fill_randomly(m, size):
    keys = np.random.random_integers(0, 0xFFFFFFFF, size)
    # 0 is a special domain-specific value
    values = np.random.random_integers(1, 0xFFFF, size)
    for j in range(size):
        m[keys[j]] = values[j]

def benchmark_get():
    cdef int dummy
    cdef uint32_t i, j, table_key
    cdef SparseHashMap m
    cdef vector[uint32_t] q_keys
    cdef int NUM_QUERIES = 1000000
    cdef uint32_t MAX_REQUEST = 7448 * 2**19 - 1  # this is domain-specific

    time_start = time.time()

    ### OPTION 1 ###
    m = SparseHashMap('17.shash')

    ### OPTION 2 ###
    # m = SparseHashMap(16130443)
    # fill_randomly(m, 16130443)

    q_keys = np.random.random_integers(0, MAX_REQUEST, NUM_QUERIES)

    print("Initialization: %.3f" % (time.time() - time_start))

    dummy = 0

    time_start = time.time()

    for i in range(NUM_QUERIES):
        table_key = q_keys[i]
        dummy += m.get(table_key)
        dummy %= 0xFFFFFF  # to prevent overflow error

    time_elapsed = time.time() - time_start

    if dummy == 42:
        # So that the unused variable is not optimized away
        print("Wow, lucky!")

    print("Table size: %d" % len(m))
    print("Total time: %.3f" % time_elapsed)
    print("Seconds per query: %.8f" % (time_elapsed / NUM_QUERIES))
    print("Queries per second: %.1f" % (NUM_QUERIES / time_elapsed))

def main():
    benchmark_get()
```

`benchmark.pyxbld` (because `pyximport` should compile in C++ mode):

```
def make_ext(modname, pyxfilename):
    from distutils.extension import Extension
    return Extension(
        name=modname,
        sources=[pyxfilename],
        language='c++'
    )
```

`run.py`:

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()

import benchmark
benchmark.main()
```

The results for `17.shash` are:

```
Initialization: 2.612
Table size: 16130443
Total time: 48.568
Seconds per query: 0.00004857
Queries per second: 20589.8
```

and for random data:

```
Initialization: 25.853
Table size: 16100260
Total time: 0.891
Seconds per query: 0.00000089
Queries per second: 1122356.3
```

The key distribution in `17.shash` is this (`plt.hist(np.fromiter(m.keys(), dtype=np.uint32, count=len(m)), bins=50)`):

[image: histogram]

From the documentation on [`sparsehash`](https://sparsehash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/implementation.html) and [`gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01206_source.html#l00118) it seems that trivial hashing is used here (that is, `x` hashes to `x`).

Is there anything obvious that could be causing this behavior besides hash collisions? From what I have found, it is non-trivial to integrate a custom hash function (i.e. overload `std::hash<uint32_t>`) in a Cython wrapper.

Comment: Interesting question, and I'm not super familiar with google's SparseHashMap -- However, I feel like I have to ask if you've considered using a python `dict` instead . . . :-)

Comment: @mgilson Of course. The problem with dicts is that they store Python objects which blow up memory through the roof. For example, `int(0)` is 24 bytes. The original code where this comes from needs a few dozen of maps which currently contain a total of around 100 000 000 elements. When I was using dicts I could allocate around 80 000 000 elements before running out of memory. `sparse_hash_map` requires less than a gigabyte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution that works, but it ain't pretty.

`sparsehash_wrapper.cpp`:

```
#include "sparsehash/sparse_hash_map"
#include "stdint.h"

// syntax borrowed from
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094104/google-sparse-hash-with-murmur-hash-function

struct UInt32Hasher {
    size_t operator()(const uint32_t& x) const {
        return (x ^ (x << 17) ^ (x >> 13) + 3238229671);
    }    
};

template<class Key, class T>
class sparse_hash_map : public google::sparse_hash_map<Key, T, UInt32Hasher> {};
```

This is a custom hash function which I could integrate in the existing wrapper with minimal code changes: I only had to replace `sparsehash/sparse_hash_map` with the path to `sparsehash_wrapper.cpp` in the Cython `.pxd` file. So far, the only problem with it is that `pyximport` cannot find `sparsehash_wrapper.cpp` unless I specify the full absolute path in `.pxd`.

The problem was indeed with collisions: after recreating a hash map with the same contents as `17.shash` from scratch (that it, creating an empty map and inserting every (key, value) pair from `17.shash` into it), the performance went up to 1M+ req/sec.